# aws educate RDS - error setting up MYSQL db

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Hello I am trying to create MYSQL db under AWS Educate account and I bump into the below error.
Any pointers will be useful.

- Free tier account
- db instance: t2 micro
- engine: MYSQL 5.7.26
- REGION: US East-1

Your request to create DB instance aws-simplified didn't work.
User: arn:aws:sts::############:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/user#######=$$$$$ is not authorized to perform: rds:CreateDBInstance on resource: arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:############:db:aws-simplified with an explicit deny

Comment: see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=309960

Comment: Thank you. I dont seem to have access to update my role with the privileges though. Can I update if I only have a BASIC account. Any pointers if these need to be done by admin ?                                                                {

Answer (score 1):

AWS Educate accounts have intentionally-limited permissions.

You should contact the AWS Educate team at: https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/